# MVC2 ajax partial view does not register jquery scripts

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-ajax

I have my page where i have ajax call to display form.
My code works when the register the code for form but not from postback (validation error in controller).
any idea how to fix this?

My container page has:

Scripts:

```
<%= Html.JQuery() %>
     <script src="../../../../Scripts/jquery.ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="../../../../Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="../../../../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="../../../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript">/script>
     <script src="../../../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
       function registerStuff() {
             //this gets triggered when onsuccess is called
             $("#date").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
             $("#sla").datepicker();
         }

     </script>
```

**Content:**

```
 <%= Ajax.AjaxButton("New action", "CreateWorkFlowAction", new {
 controller = "CaseWorkFlow" }, new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId =
 "divTableContainer", HttpMethod = "Get", OnSuccess =
 "registerStuff"})%>

      <div id="divTableContainer">
response will appear here
</div>
```

my form looks like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function RegisterJs() {
        $("#date").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
        $("#sla").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
    }
</script>
<% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateWorkFlowAction", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "divTableContainer", HttpMethod = "Post" }))
   {%>
<%= Html.ValidationSummary() %>

<fieldset>
    <div>
        <label for="title">
            Title</label>
        <%= Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Title) %>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="SLA">
            SLA(Due Date)</label>
        <%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SelectSlaDate, new { id = "sla", @Value = string.Empty} )%>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="date">
            Date</label>
        <%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SelectDate, new { id = "date", @Value = string.Empty})%>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit">Save action</button> 
    </div>
</fieldset>
<% } %>
```

the problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found the solution to my question.

I have to reregister my javascript inside of a partial view.

this means that i had to update add register scripts into the parent page to which i will insert partial view.

and therfore if my view page contains partial view i had to move

```
   function registerStuff() { 
             //this gets triggered when onsuccess is called 
             $("#date").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' }); 
             $("#sla").datepicker(); 
         }
```

to the index page.
After on success call this function "registerStuff" from my oncomplete,
and after then everything is working like charm

hope this helps to you too